# Creating element with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This line of code is not working, how can I create a DOM element and adding it a class instantly?

```
var notes = document.createElement("div").addClass("notes card-content");
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just jQuery for this :

```
$("<div/>").addClass("notes card-content");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing jQuery and JavaScript (DOM) there. `document.createElement` is a DOM method and `$.addClass` is a jQuery one.

With jQuery, you could do:

```
var notes = $("<div/>").addClass("notes card-content");
```

Or with just the browser methods you can do:

```
var notes = document.createElement("div");
notes.className = "notes card-content";
```

Finally, you can mix them together as jQuery accepts an element as its argument:

```
var notes = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("notes card-content");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix native methods like that with jQuery, it's either

```
var notes = document.createElement("div");

notes.className = 'notes card-content';
```

or with jQuery

```
var notes = $('<div />', {'class' : 'notes card-content'})
```